# Get transaction history of address using electrum commands

Tags: electrum, stratum

I am using electrum protocol to query history of a bitcoin address using `blockchain.address.get_history`.

All is good; I am receiving the tx data for every transaction. My problem is that I am unable to figure out a way to get the fee and transaction details for every tx received. (I want to use same stratum protocol if possible.)

Comment: Stratum is a mining protocol, unrelated to electrum. Please add more clarity to your question in terms of what API you are using.

Comment: The protocol used by Electrum to connect to its servers is also called stratum.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the fee by taking the sum of the value of the transaction inputs and subtracting that from the sum of the value of the transaction outputs. The fee is really just the leftover amount of a transaction that is not specifically sent as an output.

Comment: i am getting only tx hash don't know how to retrive details about that transaction

Comment: From what I see, using the electrum protocol you will then need to use blockchain.transaction.get and this will return the hex encoded transaction. You will then have to figure out a way to decode the hex.

Comment: any tips on that ?